# Slight variation in Nagios monitoring report

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I am not sure if this is an issue or I am missing something. Nagios is reporting 'check_procs' status information: PROCS OK: 188 processes; but when I run the following command directly on the server its reporting I get a different result:

Command: ps -ef |wc -l (ubuntu machine)
Result shown is 186 as against 188 its reporting.

Anyone come across this?

Answer (score 0):

cant say for sure, but my guess is, that you have 2 procs more because of this :

1. Call from Nagios running NRPE to Daemon
2. NRPE running the remote script

which means 186 + nagios Process for check + NRPE running script for answering =188